# What am I doing wrong with this syntax of multiple if - else in apply pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to execute this code:

```
data['lga_code'] = data.loc[:,'lga'].apply(lambda x: 'Rural' if x == endswith('Rural')
                                          ('Urban' if x == endswith('Urban')
                                           else 'other'))
```

But I get this error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

What is wrong?

`data` is a dataframe that it has 125 categories. I want to group them all into three, and that's what I tried.

Comment: endswith is a function of string, so x.endswith()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `else`. Also [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.endswith) return True or False. You need to write `x.endswith`.

```
data.loc[:,'lga'].apply(lambda x: 'Rural' if x.endswith('Rural')
                        else ('Urban' if x.endswith('Urban')
                              else 'other'))

### You can write without  "loc" ###
data['lga'].apply(lambda x: 'Rural' if x.endswith('Rural')
                        else ('Urban' if x.endswith('Urban')
                              else 'other'))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter problems like this, I break up my code into smaller pieces. In this case, I recommend creating a function instead of using a lambda:

```
def get_category(x):
    if x == endswith('Rural')
        return 'Rural'
    if x == endswith('Urban')
        return urban
    return 'other'
```

This is much easier to read than trying to do everything in a single line. Also, python can more easily point out where any problems are because the code is broken across multiple lines.

Now you will find that `endswith()` isn't defined. Most likely you want to call it on the string `x`:

```
def get_category(x):
    if x.endswith('Rural')
        return 'Rural'
    if x.endswith('Urban')
        return urban
    return 'other'
```

Now you can apply this function to your dataframe:

```
data['lga_code'] = data.loc[:,'lga'].apply(get_category)
```